# The sine curve with Gnuplot on a large range

Tags: gnuplot, trigonometry

Gnuplot seems to plot a very weird sine curve when I adjust the x-range to [0:200]. Here's the code :

```
gnuplot> set xrange [0:200]
gnuplot> plot sin(x)
```

and here's what Gnuplot returns :

[image: Function Sin by Gnuplot]

How can I make it plot a correct curve ?

Comment: It looks like you need to sample it at more points.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `set samples 10000` to increase the resolution of the x-axis.